# It says the following error in c++. [Error] too many arguments to function 'int rand()' in void initialise

Tags: random

```
// A C++ Program to play tic-tac-toe
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>


#define COMPUTER 1
#define HUMAN 2

#define SIDE 3 // Length of the board

// Computer will move with 'O'
// and human with 'X'
#define COMPUTERMOVE 'O'
#define HUMANMOVE 'X'

class game
{
    int i,j;
    public:void showBoard(char board[][SIDE]);
           void showInstructions();
           void initialise(char board[][SIDE], int moves[]);
           void declareWinner(int whoseTurn);
           bool rowCrossed(char board[][SIDE]);
           bool columnCrossed(char board[][SIDE]);
           bool diagonalCrossed(char board[][SIDE]);
           bool gameOver(char board[][SIDE]);
           void playTicTacToe(int whoseTurn);


};
// A function to show the current board status
void game::showBoard(char board[][SIDE])
{
    cout<<"\n\n";

    cout<<"\t\t\t  %c | %c  | %c  \n", board[0][0],
                             board[0][1], board[0][2];
    cout<<"\t\t\t--------------\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t  %c | %c  | %c  \n", board[1][0],
                             board[1][1], board[1][2];
    cout<<"\t\t\t--------------\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t  %c | %c  | %c  \n\n", board[2][0],
                             board[2][1], board[2][2];

    return;
};

// A function to show the instructions
void game::showInstructions()
{
cout<<"\t\t\t Tic-Tac-Toe\n\n";
    cout<<"Choose a cell numbered from 1 to 9 as below"
            " and play\n\n";

    cout<<"\t\t\t 1 | 2 | 3 \n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t--------------\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t 4 | 5 | 6 \n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t--------------\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t 7 | 8 | 9 \n\n";

    cout<<"-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\t-\n\n";

    return;
}


// A function to initialise the game
void game::initialise(char board[][SIDE],int moves[])
{

    int i,j;

    // Initiate the random number generator so that
    // the same configuration doesn't arises


    // Initially the board is empty
    for ( i=0; i<SIDE; i++)
    {
        for ( j=0; j<SIDE; j++)
            board[i][j] = ' ';
    }

    // Fill the moves with numbers
    for ( i=0; i<SIDE*SIDE; i++)
        moves[i] = i;

    // randomise the moves
    rand(moves, moves + SIDE*SIDE);

    return;
}

// A function to declare the winner of the game
void game::declareWinner(int whoseTurn)
{
    if (whoseTurn == COMPUTER)
        cout<<"COMPUTER has won\n";
    else
        cout<<"HUMAN has won\n";
    return;
}

// A function that returns true if any of the row
// is crossed with the same player's movet
bool rowCrossed(char board[][SIDE])
{ int i;
    for ( i=0; i<SIDE; i++)
    {
        if (board[i][0] == board[i][1] &&
            board[i][1] == board[i][2] &&
            board[i][0] != ' ')
            return (true);
    }
    return(false);
}

// A function that returns true if any of the column
// is crossed with the same player's move
bool columnCrossed(char board[][SIDE])
{ int i;
    for ( i=0; i<SIDE; i++)
    {
        if (board[0][i] == board[1][i] &&
            board[1][i] == board[2][i] &&
            board[0][i] != ' ')
            return (true);
    }
    return(false);
}

// A function that returns true if any of the diagonal
// is crossed with the same player's move
bool diagonalCrossed(char board[][SIDE])
```

1. List item

   {
       if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] &&
           board[1][1] == board[2][2] &&
           board[0][0] != ' ')
           return(true);

   ```
   if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] &&
       board[1][1] == board[2][0] &&
       board[0][2] != ' ')
       return(true);

   return(false);
   ```

   }

   // A function that returns true if the game is over
   // else it returns a false
   bool gameOver(char board[][SIDE])
   {
       return(rowCrossed(board) || columnCrossed(board)
               || diagonalCrossed(board) );
   }

   // A function to play Tic-Tac-Toe
   void game::playTicTacToe(int whoseTurn)
   {

   ```
   // A 3*3 Tic-Tac-Toe board for playing

   char board[SIDE][SIDE];

   int moves[SIDE*SIDE];


   // Initialise the game
   initialise(board, moves);

   // Show the instructions before playing
   showInstructions();

   int moveIndex = 0, x, y;

   // Keep playing till the game is over or it is a draw
   while (gameOver(board) == false &&
           moveIndex != SIDE*SIDE)
   {
       if (whoseTurn == COMPUTER)
       {
           x = moves[moveIndex] / SIDE;
           y = moves[moveIndex] % SIDE;
           board[x][y] = COMPUTERMOVE;
           cout<<"COMPUTER has put a %c in cell %d\n",
                   COMPUTERMOVE, moves[moveIndex]+1;
           showBoard(board);
           moveIndex ++;
           whoseTurn = HUMAN;
       }

       else if (whoseTurn == HUMAN)
       {
           x = moves[moveIndex] / SIDE;
           y = moves[moveIndex] % SIDE;
           board[x][y] = HUMANMOVE;
           printf ("HUMAN has put a %c in cell %d\n",
                   HUMANMOVE, moves[moveIndex]+1);
           showBoard(board);
           moveIndex ++;
           whoseTurn = COMPUTER;
       }
   }

   // If the game has drawn
   if (gameOver(board) == false &&
           moveIndex == SIDE * SIDE)
       printf("It's a draw\n");
   else
   {
       // Toggling the user to declare the actual
       // winner
       if (whoseTurn == COMPUTER)
           whoseTurn = HUMAN;
       else if (whoseTurn == HUMAN)
           whoseTurn = COMPUTER;

       // Declare the winner
       declareWinner(whoseTurn);
   }
   return;
   ```

   }

   // Driver program
   int main()
   {
       // Let us play the game with COMPUTER starting first
        playTicTacToe(COMPUTER);
           srand(time(NULL));

   ```
   return (0);
   ```

   }

Comment: What language is this?  Looks like C++, but a tag would help get the right eyes on it.

Comment: Also, assuming this is C++, the code you posted isn't close to valid.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @StephenNewell,yes it is a c++ code

Comment: Please add explicit in text info that it is C++ and what is really the question.